# Non-zero dipole moment of parahydroxy phenol

Tags: organic-chemistry, dipole

How can we explain the non-zero dipole moment of parahydroxy phenol? I know that it cannot be explained by inductive effect, and has something to do with resonance, but still how can we say it is non-zero? I mean, since it's symmetrical, even the resonance effect should cancel out, right?